# GAE app consuming other GAE app services. Is that a good approach?

Tags: google-app-engine, rest

I'm building an application on Google AppEngine (GAE). This app will serve rest services to be consumed by mobile devices or ordinary computers such as desktops.
Mobile devices will have native frontend. In other hand, desktops will access a web frontend through web browsers. So, I'm wondering if it's a good approach to build a web frontend
in a separate application hosted on GAE. This way, there will be two applications hosted on GAE. The first one (that with the rest services) will be consumed by the second one and also by mobile devices.
Would it be a good practice on GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While technically possible, you might be breaking the TOS because its really the same app consuming quotas from 2 appengines. Some people do that to get extra free quotas thus google doesnt like it.
You should be able to put frontend and backend in the same appengine.

Comment: I got it. That's what I wanted to know.So, I'll put both app on same appengine. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are basically describing app engine modules: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/